# angularjs pushing string to array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I got a problem in how an array is formatted, here is my example :

```
var code = 743919183;
var tempPost = '["'+code+'"]';
$scope.arrayTwo = [];
$scope.arrayTwo.push(code);
```

when in console :

tempPost will output like this :
`["743919183"]`

while `$scope.arrayTwo`, have space before and after doublequotes
      `[ "743919183" ]`

I want to have `$scope.ArrayTwo` array is formatted just like `tempPost`, how do i do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What's the purpose?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but:

```
var code = 743919183; //This is an integer to convert to string just call .toString()
var tempPost = '["'+code+'"]'; //This is a string that has a value equal to "["743919183"]", this is not an array.
$scope.arrayTwo = [] //This is a an empty array;
$scope.arrayTwo.push(code); //This will add a new item to the array in this case the integer code. Your array would look like [743919183].
```

Now, if what you want is an array that has one item that is code as a string you should do:

```
var code = "743919183";
$scope.arrayTwo = [code];
```

Or:

```
var code = 743919183;
$scope.arrayTwo = [code.toString()];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to look like array format without being an actual array you can do this:

```
var code = 743919183;
var tempPost = '["'+code+'"]';
$scope.arrayTwo = [];
$scope.arrayTwo.push(code);
```

Is that what you are going for?

OR you can do this

```
var code = 743919183;
$scope.arrayTwo = [];

function Str2Arr() {

  s = '';

  for (var i=0; i<code.length; i++) {

    if (code[i] != ',') { s += code[i]; }

                  else { arrayTwo .push(s);  s = ''; }

  } 

  arrayTwo .push(s);

  alert(arrayTwo .join('\n'));

}

Str2Arr();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var code = 743919183;
var tempPost = '["'+code+'"]';
$scope.arrayTwo = [];
$scope.arrayTwo.push(code);
```

in firefox `$scope.arrayTwo` return [ "743919183" ] and chrome ["743919183"](no space in chrome). so i think this  should not be create problem in code.

Comment: it will be a problem when i try to grab the data using `$_PHP['products']` for example.... the `$scope.arrayTwo` is in false format....but when i try to post `tempPost` , it work